# EF 6 - Client side LINQ evaluation Logging

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

Wondering is there a way to figure out whether my Linq queries were evaluated at the client or the server side, may be via some flag, log etc?

We are migrating EF6 to EFCore 6 and since client side evaluation is disabled in EFCore6, hence we need to know what all queries will fail to be exported from EF6.

Comment: EF Core 6 do not do client evaluation. It is not logged, it just fails with exception and only after execution.

Comment: Just look at queries featuring any type of grouping. They may not be supported in EFC 6, meaning you'll have to *add* client-side evaluation. Since EF6 doesn't have any client-side evaluation I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I think you mis read my question— I meant EF6 client side evaluation not EfF Core 6

Comment: @GertArnold Not sure what do you mean when you say EF6 doesn’t have client side evaluation? EF6 does lot of translations and execution of linq queries irrespective of the query being able to get converted to SQL fully or not.

Comment: Yeah, OK, in that sense all ORMs do client-side evaluation. Like converting a SQL result set into an object graph. And EF6 supports grouping, sometimes even w/o translating it into a SQL `group by` statement. But "client-side evaluation" in EF terms means auto-dividing server-side and client-side executable parts within one LINQ statement. Only EFC1 and 2 did that. It was abandoned in EFC3. And EFC still does it if the client-side part is in the final `Select`.

Comment: @GertArnold right, agree with your points but I want to know if in EF6 itself there’s a way to detect Linq queries execution’s strategy. I am sure in EF6, the expression visitor must be written in such manner which distinguishes and divides the query. All I want is some kind of Warning/logging that states ‘hey EF6 encountered a query which needs client eval’. P.S. I know the behavior exists in EFC1 and EFC2 and not in EFC3 and onwards.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Any ideas on EF6 itself to gather info about LINQs involving client side evaluation?

Comment: @GertArnold Any further suggestions on EF6 version itself?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava, if EF6 do not provide such information, then there is no easy way.  And I never used EF 6. Actually EF Core 6 may fail with grouping and there a lot of workarounds.